# Stored procedure to generate sequential guid for all tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

This may well be a duplicate but I can't seem to find anything close enough to my use case.

Due to various reasons like views, instead of triggers and so on, I'm unable to use the `OUTPUT` clause with an `INSERT` statement to retrieve the system generated `GUID` with `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`.

An idea which I have, is to rather generate the `GUID` using a stored procedure:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

IF ( OBJECT_ID( N'[dbo].[GETNEXTGUID]' ) IS NOT Null )
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID]
    (@NextId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sequence TABLE([KEY] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(), [DUMMY] BIT);

    INSERT INTO @Sequence ([DUMMY]) VALUES (0);

    SELECT @NextId = [KEY] FROM @Sequence;
END
GO

DECLARE @NextId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

EXECUTE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID] @NextId OUTPUT;

PRINT @NextId;
```

The generated `GUID` can then be inserted into the table and should also alleviate the issue that plagues `IDENTITY` columns with `@@IDENTITY`, `IDENT_CURRENT`, etc.

I don't have sufficient knowledge even after testing to authoritatively say whether this is truly a working solution or simply a long winded way of applying a "somewhat" cleaner `NEWID()` due to the fact that it's using a temp table which is being destroyed after every call.

I tried using TWO temp tables and their sequential numbers seem to tie up and running the procedure consecutively also seems to tie up.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

IF (OBJECT_ID( N'[dbo].[GETNEXTGUID]') IS NOT Null)
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID]
    (@NextId1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
     @NextId2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sequence1 TABLE ([KEY] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(), [DUMMY] BIT);
    DECLARE @Sequence2 TABLE ([KEY] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(), [DUMMY] BIT);

    INSERT INTO @Sequence1 ([DUMMY]) VALUES (0);
    INSERT INTO @Sequence2 ([DUMMY]) VALUES (0);

    SELECT @NextId1 = [KEY] FROM @Sequence1;
    SELECT @NextId2 = [KEY] FROM @Sequence2;
END
GO

DECLARE @NextId1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
DECLARE @NextId2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

EXECUTE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID] @NextId1 OUTPUT, @NextId2 OUTPUT;
PRINT @NextId1; PRINT @NextId2;

EXECUTE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID] @NextId1 OUTPUT, @NextId2 OUTPUT;
PRINT @NextId1; PRINT @NextId2;

EXECUTE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID] @NextId1 OUTPUT, @NextId2 OUTPUT;
PRINT @NextId1; PRINT @NextId2;

EXECUTE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID] @NextId1 OUTPUT, @NextId2 OUTPUT;
PRINT @NextId1; PRINT @NextId2;

EXECUTE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID] @NextId1 OUTPUT, @NextId2 OUTPUT;
PRINT @NextId1; PRINT @NextId2;
```

Result:

```
AAAFD869-E814-EA11-A2FA-00155D0A020C
ABAFD869-E814-EA11-A2FA-00155D0A020C
ACAFD869-E814-EA11-A2FA-00155D0A020C
ADAFD869-E814-EA11-A2FA-00155D0A020C
AEAFD869-E814-EA11-A2FA-00155D0A020C
AFAFD869-E814-EA11-A2FA-00155D0A020C
B0AFD869-E814-EA11-A2FA-00155D0A020C
B1AFD869-E814-EA11-A2FA-00155D0A020C
B2AFD869-E814-EA11-A2FA-00155D0A020C
B3AFD869-E814-EA11-A2FA-00155D0A020C
```

I'd appreciate input from someone with more experience offering their insights.

Comment: Personally, I don't like using guids for primary keys, especially if they are also the clustered index of their table (which is the default case in SQL Server). Why not simply use a sequence to generate an Int or bigInt instead?

Comment: Considering that it appears you want this cross tables, a sequence does appear to be the best option.

Comment: Or simply go with a natural key instead of a surrogate one...

Comment: Hi, this isn't for the primary key, it's a replacement for sequential numbers on certain tables/insertable views that go across servers, etc. where sequential numbers won't suffice as the surrogate key.

Comment: If it's not indexed, you can simply use `newId()`. The `SequestialId()` function is good when you need indexed guids.

Comment: Did you try this from several sessions? Open a new Query window and call the same EXEC... I do not know, what you really need (might be a XY-problem), but I think, that a *declared table variable* does not continue the sequence... you might use a physical table to ensure the sequential ID generation...

Comment: @Shnugo According to documentation: "Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by this function on a specified computer since Windows was started. After restarting Windows, the GUID can start again from a lower range, but is still globally unique."

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Yes, but the code above is obviously a list of GUIDs increasing one by one. Copying the EXEC to a new query will not continue with `B4AF..`. I do not know, waht the OP wants to achive...

Comment: For the requirement, I can only use a single column as a surrogate key, normally this would be the identity column but because it has to work across servers it needs to become a unique identity instead.  As mentioned I can't use OUTPUT in my statement and therefore need to generate the GUID prior to inserting the record.  Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I created the following stored procedure to test with. It creates 2 temp tables which will show whether the id's generated are in fact sequential.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

IF (OBJECT_ID( N'[dbo].[GETNEXTGUID]') IS NOT Null)
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID]
(
    @NextId1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
    @NextId2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sequence1 TABLE ([KEY] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(), [DUMMY] BIT);
    DECLARE @Sequence2 TABLE ([KEY] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(), [DUMMY] BIT);

    INSERT INTO @Sequence1 ([DUMMY]) VALUES (0);
    INSERT INTO @Sequence2 ([DUMMY]) VALUES (0);

    SELECT @NextId1 = [KEY] FROM @Sequence1;
    SELECT @NextId2 = [KEY] FROM @Sequence2;
END
GO
```

I then ran the following test across multiple connections at the same time.  So the test will call it's own two persisted tables as well as the two temp tables within the stored procedure.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

DECLARE @Sequence1 TABLE ([KEY] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(), [DUMMY] BIT);
DECLARE @Sequence2 TABLE ([KEY] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(), [DUMMY] BIT);
DECLARE @Count int = 0;
DECLARE @NextId1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
DECLARE @NextId2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

WHILE ( @Count < 100000 )
BEGIN
    EXECUTE [dbo].[GETNEXTGUID] @NextId1 OUTPUT, @NextId2 OUTPUT;
    PRINT @NextId1; PRINT @NextId2;

    INSERT INTO @Sequence1 ([DUMMY]) VALUES (0);
    INSERT INTO @Sequence2 ([DUMMY]) VALUES (0);

    SELECT @NextId1 = [KEY] FROM @Sequence1;
    SELECT @NextId2 = [KEY] FROM @Sequence2;

    PRINT @NextId1; PRINT @NextId2;

    SET @Count += 1;
END
GO
```

Taking the results from the various connections and sorting them showed that the sequence is sequential across all 4 tables, regardless of whether they're persisted or recreated with each call and therefore will fit the requirement perfectly.

Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, what you really need, but you might try something along this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.testSeq_13Byte AS DECIMAL(28); /*read about START WITH to enforce a range*/
GO
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.testSeq_13Byte;
GO
SELECT CAST(CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.testSeq_13Byte AS VARBINARY(16)) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
```

According to the docs a `DECIMAL(28)` takes 13 bytes, a `DECIMAL(38)` lives in 17 bytes and a GUID is using 16 bytes.

The numeric range of `DECIMAL(28)` is huge... you can cast this to `VARBINARY(16)` and this to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`. This should return a *new id* with a system-wide logic.

If you need this, you might even cast this back to a `DECIMAL(28)`.

But we should keep in mind, that it is always a bit dangerous to rely on the internal binary representation of a datatype. This might change from version to version...

Comment: Thanks, but this won't be safe to use across multiple servers unless you specify the range per server?

Comment: @Storm each server might have its own ID, which you can include. This would create something like a range per server without thinking about the maths

Comment: thanks, the premise is indeed intriguing but I have no access to the servers or their databases and therefore needed to create something that doesn't rely on any interaction, hence why I originally went for the GUID since that already takes the machine into account.

Comment: @Storm you can use any constant value. What about a single-column-table with just one constant? Can you create this?

Comment: @Storm what about the server's name?

Comment: @Storm And you might store a table wherever you want with a mapping of server name and an ID for this sever. Then stuff this into the byte chain

Comment: for all the above a simple GUID will solve the issues?  I'm not sure why the insistence on using something other than a GUID.

Comment: @Storm, my first line is *I do not know, what you really need*. Your question was not really clear... I got the impression, that you are looking for something like a *multi-server-wide sequence*. Your posted solution is fine, but is not sequential in any case (e.g. when moving this database to another machine)...